# Set parameters that can be passed from a batch file to a c# file

Tags: c#, batch-file

I set my variables in a batch file and I want to pass them into a c# file.  From what I have found out looking online when passing parameter in a batch file they need to be in form %1 %2 etc.  How do I get my variables into %1 %2?  Here is my code

```
@echo off
:: Open Labels

@echo off 

 set name="Aaron "
 ECHO var=%name%
 set company=Company"
 ECHO var=%company%
"C:\Users\akatz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe %1 %2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%1` and `%2` represent what was passed into the batch file. Use your custom variables the same way you do in the echo command:

```
"C:\...\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" %name% %company%
```

For testing, you can prefix the line with an echo to see what it generates without executing.

```
echo "C:\...\WindowsFormsApplication1.exe" %name% %company%
```

Answer (score 1):

Change %1 to %name% and %2 to %company%.